# Json for caching tables.. is that good Idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, caching

**Current State :**

I work at Project Asp.net , it is about reading data from DB and mapping it to a datagrid into webpage. everything is okay , except that response time while the pagination, I know in each time I paginate the table (1 of 50 pages) that will be queried the DB so that's wrong ..

**What I plan to do :**

enhance the performance of reading data to be more faster . like hitting the DB one time to cache all the data into json file then reuse this for datagrid after mapping them..

**or if any idea more better:**

for caching these tables for while then use it for pagination .. lifetime of data will expire after the page closed!

Comment: ASP.NET has already `cache` in it, have you tried storing there? -> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/caching-in-asp-net-mvc. Also you can use 3rd party tools like https://redis.io/.

Comment: Yes thank you, it was more efficient, that turns me on many ways.. But this cashing doesn't work with asp.net core, i got error referring to conflicts between two mvc versions.. Actually versions of frameworks.. The caching of the output will work in asp.net core only with repose attributes.. Anyway it works..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: if you want to cache data, you can use `System.Runtime.MemoryCache` or a static dictionary. Json is a horrible idea for a cache.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a scenario where the data is loaded to a js DataTable on client-side and from here, users can interact with the grid (CRUD) before sending it back to the server.

Though, using JSON as a cache on the client slide at first load and let the user play with the data is my solution in this case since it dramatically reduces the server load and data binding.

Please share your thought and it would be nice if you can spare some knowledge on this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation of how much time the data changes.

If so many changing, than would be better to improve internal database caching or query result caching.

Otherwise you can use in front caching mechanism, like use memory for caching (*) the data/query result. A place where you can put any cached file.

(*)
Layer External:
redis, memcached, etc

Layer Application:
- Shared memory (that could be accessed by many requests/sessions at same time).